# How to send multiple messages over a socket using Asynchronous conection on c#

Tags: c#, sockets, asyncsocket

I'm trying to adapt the Microsoft example code for:

"Asynchronous Server Socket" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example

and "Asynchronous Client Socket" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-client-socket-example

what I'm trying to do is adapt the client application and make it capable of sending multiple messages to the server without closing the client application. I was trying with an infinite test loop, but when I sent the second message I got the error:

[image: The error]
Here is my connect method on the client application:

```
public void connect()
        {

            while (true)
            {

                // Conectarse a un dispositivo remoto  
                try
                {



                        // Establish the remote endpoint for the socket
                        IPEndPoint direccion = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 45000);

                        // Create a TCP/IP socket.  
                        Socket client = new Socket(direccion.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

                        // Connect to the remote endpoint.  
                        client.BeginConnect(direccion, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
                        connectDone.WaitOne();

                        // Send test data to the remote device.  
                        Console.WriteLine("Write your message bellow");
                        String data_s = Console.ReadLine();
                        Send(client, data_s);
                        sendDone.WaitOne();

                        // Receive the response from the remote device.  
                        Receive(client);
                        receiveDone.WaitOne();

                        // Write the response to the console.  
                        Console.WriteLine("Response received : {0}", response);

                        // Release the socket.  
                        client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                        client.Close();
                    }


                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Aqui esta el error");
                    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                }
            }

}
```

It should be noted that I do not have much experience in the socket programming, so I'm not sure if the connect method is the right spot to get into and solve the problem. The rest of the code of the server app and client app is the same, I only changed connect method and a couple of validations That Should't be the problem.

I tried only loop this code block:

```
// Send test data to the remote device.  
                        Console.WriteLine("Write your message bellow");
                        String data_s = Console.ReadLine();
                        Send(client, data_s);
                        sendDone.WaitOne();

                        // Receive the response from the remote device.  
                        Receive(client);
                        receiveDone.WaitOne();

                        // Write the response to the console.  
                        Console.WriteLine("Response received : {0}", response);
```

but I got:

[image: Estabilished connection aborted]

Comment: That code is basically the opposite of sending multiple messages over a single connection. The only thing that should be called in your loop is from `// Send test data to the remote device.` to the `Response received` message

Comment: If I do that I got another error :(. I'll update my question